# Launching a new EC2 instance. Status Reason: Not authorized for images: Launching EC2 instance failed

Tags: amazon-web-services, autoscaling

I recently created an auto scaling group in AWS using an AMI. The instance terminated and in an attempt to re-launch the instance, I got a failed response.
The error description is

> Launching a new EC2 instance. Status Reason: Not authorized for images: [ami-096daa92e8b4e4927]. Launching EC2 instance failed.

Answer (score 3):

You can only use public AMIs and private AMIs that were explicitly shared with you. If you used a private AMI that is no longer shared with you, then you can no longer start instances with that AMI. In the future, if you intend to use a private AMI that was shared with you, you should copy the AMI first, in case the original is unshared or deleted, then use your private copy of the AMI to start instances.

Comment: So is there any way the AMI can be authorized for the auto scaling group?

Comment: @N.Felix The owner of the AMI would need to share it with you again.

Comment: If your using Windows, and the default public AMI provided by AWS, those AMI's become private about every 3 months since the security updates on them are out of date